# Optimizing reportviewer to not get outofmemory exception

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer

We have implemented a process using C# and reportviewer to create PDFs by the localreport.render method.

When we have to process a big file, say more than 20000 records, the process fails with outofmemory exception error. I know there may be lot of causes for this error but what I want to know is, if the below code is okay or if you expert can give me a better solution.

I have about 40 case statements each calling different .rdlc files and it is based on the type (I did not include all the case statements due to lack of space).

`USP_Select_Batch_Address_To_Sort` is a dataset defined in the solution executing a stored procedure accepting three parameters (in this case batch, run and sequence#).

So is this approach feasible? What other solution can you provide?

```
public static void GenerateIndividualPDFs(string batch, string run, MainDataSet1 DS, MainDataSet1TableAdapters.USP_Select_Batch_Address_To_SortTableAdapter Ta, BindingSource bs, int intStart = 0, int intEnd = 0, string strLetterType = "")
        {
            reportDataSource.Name = "DataSet1";
            reportDataSource.Value = bs;
            int count;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter;

            var batchinfo = new clsBatchInfo();

            ReportViewer report = new ReportViewer();

            report.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);


            if (!Directory.Exists(mstrFilePath + "\\" + batch + run))
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(mstrFilePath + "\\" + batch + run);
            }
            var DA = new clsGetBatchSort();

            //this dataAdapter will print the full set
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(DA.dsBatch_Sort(batch, run));


            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

            int i = 0;
            int LetterTypeID = 0;

            report.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

  foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                i++;
                report.Clear();
                Ta.ClearBeforeFill = true;
                try
                {


                LetterTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(dr[2]);
                switch (LetterTypeID)
                {
                    case 1:                                      
                {

                    Ta.Fill(DS.USP_Select_Batch_Address_To_Sort, Convert.ToDecimal(batch), run,  Convert.ToInt32(dr["MPresortID"]));
                    report.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportsApplication1.ABC.MAENG.rdlc";
                    ExportReport(Convert.ToInt32(dr["MPresortID"]), batch, run, report);
                    continue;
                }
                    case 2:
                {
                     Ta.Fill(DS.USP_Select_Batch_Address_To_Sort, Convert.ToDecimal(batch), run,  Convert.ToInt32(dr["MPresortID"]));
                    report.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportsApplication1.ABC.MASPA.rdlc";
                    ExportReport(Convert.ToInt32(dr["MPresortID"]), batch, run, report);
                    continue;
                }
 catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    clsEmail.EmailMessage("Error Batch " + batch + run, "clsGenerateLetters " + ex.Message);
                    continue;
                    //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    //return "";
                }
            }
}

 private static void ExportReport(int PreSortID, string batch, string run, ReportViewer Report)
      {           

          Report.RefreshReport();

          Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamids;
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string filenameExtension;

            string fmt = "00000000";



            byte[] bytes = Report.LocalReport.Render(
                "PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
                out streamids, out warnings);

            string filename = mstrFilePath + "\\" + batch + run + "\\" + PreSortID.ToString(fmt) + ".PDF";
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
            {
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                fs.Close();
            }
            Report.LocalReport.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain();
      }
```

Comment: @WilliamBarbosa The code currently isn't working.  Not-working code belongs on SO.

Comment: I imagine the issue happens on this line? `byte[] bytes = Report.LocalReport.Render`